# getting item with max frequency from multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, multiple-columns, frequency

I have a dataframe like this:

```
a1  a2  a3  a4
4   4   4   4
4   4   4   4
2   3   2   3
2   3   3   3
2   2   2   2
2   2   2   2
```

Desired output:

```
a1  a2  a3  a4  max_freq
4   4   4   4   4
4   4   4   4   4
2   3   2   3   3
2   3   3   3   3
2   2   2   2   2
2   2   2   2   2
```

I want to return the element from column, that occurs the most horizontally in columns a1,a2,a3,a4. e.g. 4 freq -4, so max_freq=4 and so on. In case of ties, return a4.

I started off with something like:

```
def get_max_freq(row):
    unique, counts = np.unique(np.array(row), return_counts=True)
    print (unique,counts)

df_temp.apply(get_max_freq, axis=1)
```

I am able to get frequency of items row wise. i can go on and try converting them into a dataframe, sort by count and select first element and return from function, but it seems to be a slow method. Is there any pythonic way to address this problem? (which can address the speed on a ~1m rows dataframe)

Comment: You say in case of ties, return `a4`, but row 2 is a tie and you don't return `a4`

Comment: sorry corrected

Comment: What if the value in `a4` isn't even being considered for ties?

Comment: oh, it may look like replica of a4 for these small rows, but that's not the case. I am ok with getting mode for all rows, without focusing on a4 as of now, but i need it to be fast, using df.mode(1) is really damn slow

Comment: @VanPeer thats highest value, not highest frequency.

Comment: @muni so you need it to be fast? How big is your data frame?

Comment: ~1m rows in the dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're concerned about speed, and don't care about the restraint on `a4` as you mentioned in the comments, you can use **`scipy.stats.mode`**:

```
df['freq'] = scipy.stats.mode(df.values, 1)[0]

   a1  a2  a3  a4  freq
0   4   4   4   4     4
1   4   4   4   4     4
2   2   3   2   3     2
3   2   3   3   3     3
4   2   2   2   2     2
5   2   2   2   2     2
```

***Timings***

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

In [244]: %timeit df.mode(1)
12.7 s ± 268 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [245]: %timeit scipy.stats.mode(df.values, 1)[0]
10.8 ms ± 515 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This will give you a *massive* performance boost over `mode(1)`

Comment: Yea,  he says in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654821/getting-item-with-max-frequency-from-multiple-columns-in-a-dataframe/51655400#comment90273796_51654821) he doesn't care about that constraint as much as long as it's faster I think

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner.  +1

Comment: @ScottBoston thank you! It's funny how introducing a seemingly simple constraint can make a problem so much more difficult :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want `pd.Series.mode`

```
df['max_freq'] = df.agg(lambda x: x.mode() if x.mode().size==1 else x['a4'], axis=1)

    a1  a2  a3  a4  max_freq
0   4   4   4   4   4
1   4   4   4   4   4
2   2   3   2   3   3
3   2   3   3   3   3
4   2   2   2   2   2
5   2   2   2   2   2
```